# Dynamic Y Position of TextField through iterations of a loop

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs6

I have a function called `dataLoaded` that has multiple loops through a nested array full of ingredient items. The aim is to insert each item from the array into a TextField which forms part of a scrolling list. My array structure is like so:

```
public var so:SharedObject = SharedObject.getLocal("mySharedObject");
public var meat_items_array:Array = new Array(so.data.meat1, so.data.meat2, so.data.meat3);
public var carb_items_array:Array = new Array(so.data.carbs1, so.data.carbs2, so.data.carbs3);
public var other_items_array:Array = new Array(so.data.other1, so.data.other2, so.data.other3);
public var mealtype_items_array:Array = new Array(so.data.mealtype1, so.data.mealtype2, so.data.mealtype3);
public var cuisine_items_array:Array = new Array(so.data.cuisine1, so.data.cuisine2, so.data.cuisine3);
public var veg_items_array:Array = new Array(so.data.veg1, so.data.veg2, so.data.veg3);
public var master_array:Array = new Array(meat_items_array, carb_items_array, other_items_array, mealtype_items_array, cuisine_items_array, veg_items_array);
```

Here is my `dataLoaded` function:

```
private function dataLoaded():void
{
    for ( var masterCounter:int = 0; masterCounter < master_array.length; masterCounter++ )
    {
        for (var nestedCounter:int=0;nestedCounter<master_array[masterCounter].length;nestedCounter++)
        {
            var txt:String = master_array[masterCounter][nestedCounter];
            if (txt==null) continue;
            populateItem(txt,nestedCounter);
        }
    }
}
```

Originally all of the aesthetic positioning of items in the scrolling list below were done within the `dataLoaded` function but I have now decided to move all of these things into a new function called `populateItems` which is called during every iteration of the inner `for` loop in `dataLoaded`.

This all works well, except for the fact that the line `_item.y = nestedCount * _itemPosition;` no longer works as it should (originally items would be placed sequentially in a list, with the `y` value being calculated by multiplying a constant (`_itemPosition`) by the value of the counter for each iteration of the inner `for` loop). Now, 3 items are inputted into the list at once, and in the next iteration of the loop, another 3 items are placed right on top of the previous 3 items, obscuring them.

How do I change my below function so that my `_itemPosition` is more dynamic through the iterations of the `dataLoaded` function?

```
function populateItem(txt:String, nestedCount:Number):void {
    _item = new Item();
    _item.item_btn_over.alpha = 0;
    _itemTextField = new TextField();
    _itemTextField.x = _textFieldXPosition;
    _itemTextField.y = _textFieldYPosition
    _itemTextField.text = txt; 
    //adds textfield to displaylist//
    _item.addChild(_itemTextField);
    //vertical positioning//
    _item.y = nestedCount * _itemPosition; // ????
    //adds items to container displaylist//
    _container.addChild(_item);
}
```

Comment: you don't show how `_itemPosition` is set/updated

Comment: Are you just wanting all your `Item`s aligned vertically in a sequence?

Comment: @LondonDrugs_MediaServices Yes, but I have the feeling that the structure of my functions will impede any simple solutions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely clear as to what your trying to do, but assuming this code only runs once, this should do what you want:

```
_item.y = _container.height + padding;  //this will always put the next item at the bottom of the container after the previous one (padding can be any number you want)
```

Here is how this works,  let's say you have 3 objects that you are sequentially adding to `container` in a loop and you're giving each item the y value of `container.height`. Let's also assume each item has a `height` of 10:

**Loop 1:**

- Container height is `0` (since there are presently no items in it) 
  So item1's `y` is `0`
- after `container.addChild(item1)` container
  height becomes 10 (the height of item1)

  **Loop 2:**
- item2's `y` is set to container.height, which is presently 10
- after `container.addChild(item2)` container height becomes 20

  **Loop 3:**
- item3's `y` is set to container.height, which is presently 20
- after `container.addChild(item3)` container height becomes 30

---

If your code is being run multiple times (so `_container` already has objects in it), then simply run a function like this whenever you need to rearrange:

```
function orderItem():void {
    var padding:int = 5;   //5 pixel gap between items
    var tmpY:Number = 0;
    var tmpItem:DisplayObject;

    for(var i:int=0;i<_container.numChildren;i++){
        tmpItem = _container.getChildAt(i);
        tmpItem.y = tmpY;

        tmpY += tmpItem.height + padding;
    }
}
```

This goes through every child of `_container` and stacks the items vertically.

---

As an aside, it would be much cleaner to take all this:

```
            _item.item_btn_over.alpha = 0;
            _itemTextField = new TextField();
            _itemTextField.x = _textFieldXPosition;
            _itemTextField.y = _textFieldYPosition
            _itemTextField.text = txt; 
            //adds textfield to displaylist//
            _item.addChild(_itemTextField);
```

and put it in the constructor of `Item`, then pass in `txt` as a constructor argument

Comment: I originally adapted this tutorial here for the scrolling list: http://active.tutsplus.com/tutorials/actionscript/create-a-smooth-rolling-scroller-with-as3/ The _container holds all of the items together, I don't see how it could be used to position the items below one another?

Comment: If all your objects are children of the same container, then it's quite easy actually!   I'll update my answer to explain how it works

Comment: Yes they are all children of the _container. The relationship of all scrolling list elements is _container > _item > _itemTextField

Comment: Thank you very much, this explains things very well. I will implement this now

Comment: Hmm, I'm very sorry but I was unable to get your solution working. I tried to set the textField.y value as _container.height but it just left huge spaces between the items. Easier way for you to get an idea of what's going wrong is if I just link you to a zip of my project on my website. I've rolled back the changes I made to back before I posted the question so you can get an idea of the state of play (http://www.wherelionsroam.co.uk/resources/SupaCook.zip)

Comment: It will probably work if you set the `.autoSize` property of your textfield to `"left"`.  Otherwise the text field will be bigger than the actual text it contains, which is likely causing your gap.

Comment: Thank you, that seemed to do the job.